# Prevent empty Post Title on form submit via front end post (wp_insert_post_)

Tags: front-end, wp-insert-post, validation

I am creating a post from the front end using (shortened for brevity);

```
if (empty($_POST['my_title'])){  
    echo 'error: please insert a title';
} else {  
    $title =  $_POST['my_title'];
} 

$new_post = array(
'post_title'    => $title,
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_type'     => 'post'

$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

If no Post Title is present on **submit** then the form returns the error message,

**error: please insert a title**

However WordPress still inserts the post with a title of **(no title)**.

Is there a way through simple PHP validation to prevent `wp_insert_post` from accepting an empty value? *(without using Javascript)*.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put the `wp_insert_post` call inside your conditional check so its only called if the post title is not empty, something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['my_title'])){  
    echo 'error: please insert a title';
} else {  
    $title =  $_POST['my_title'];
    $new_post = array(
     'post_title'    => $title,
     'post_status'   => 'publish',
     'post_type'     => 'post');
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);  
}
```

Comment: You know I did this the first time around in my original code, but it did not work due to a typo so I've been hitting my head against a wall for 2hrs like a clown; thanks for reconfirming with the correct structure - appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could just

```
return;
```

after echoing the error. :)

Comment: That would've been my preferred choice but as soon as you `return;` you realize the script will halt at that point and not print the rest of the page.